# Is this picture of UPS man with burning Twin Towers in the background genuine?

Tags: 9-11, photography

I saw a [photo](https://imgur.com/gallery/EqqXnIX) today of a UPS carrier walking on the street that did not seem bothered by Twin Towers burning behind him. Is it genuine?

[image: UPS carrier on 9/11]

Comment: Sounds genuine to me. Source: https://www.facebook.com/WNYC/posts/10152340486136080

Comment: "Welp, bad stuff is happening, but the news reports my tax dollars are hard at work dealing with the problem.  Nothing special I can do by going there; I might as well do what I can to help some people today - deliver packages"  Anecdotally, I was performing plays (near Seattle) at the time.  Show must go on (although the audiences were mostly schools groups and so some stayed away...)

Answer (score 21):

WNYC's *On the Media* [published a story about the photo](http://www.onthemedia.org/story/157708-same-time-twin-towers-were-falling-there-were-people-having-toothaches/).

The author is Melanie Einzig, and you can see it in her "USA" gallery on her photography website: http://www.witnessx.com/street/usa/

This shows that the author presents the photo as genuine, and that the claim passed *On the Media*'s editorial process. *On the Media* has a reputation for accuracy and fact-checking, having previously won a Peabody Award, and other awards for investigative reporting, press criticism, and media criticism.

A print of the photo was [exhibited at London, Somerset House, Cartier-Bresson: A Question of Colour, 8 November 2012 – 27 January 2013](https://www.phillips.com/detail/MELANIE-EINZIG/UK040113/115).

That exhibition [self-described](http://www.somersethouse.org.uk/about/press/press-releases/cartier-bresson-a-question-of-colour):

> Positive View will present the very best in contemporary photography from across the globe and this exhibition will be no exception

Comment: Euu. I see you got that interview from the facebook link I posted; I didn't post it because that doesn't prove anything (just because the photographer claims it is true doesn't necessarily mean it is true).

Comment: @GeorgeChalhoub What kind of evidence would you consider worthy, if not the testimony of a credible witness?  Something like error level analysis?  http://fotoforensics.com/tutorial-ela.php

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede That is an excellent resource I'd never heard of. For the lazy, here is the [analysis](http://fotoforensics.com/analysis.php?id=865c0efd59a3191ee68335c80aaf05403b849d31.215349&show=ela) for this picture.